# The remote endpoint was in state [TEXT_FULL_WRITING] - websocket

Tags: java, angularjs, real-time, java-websocket

I have a web application using java web and angularJs in the client. There is real time data happening in the server and I want the client (browser) to be updated everytime something happens.

I am currently using web socket for that, where I connect to the server and receive data in the 'onMessage' method.

Here is part of the code:

```
 var ws = $websocket('ws://' + location.host + '/' +    window.location.href.split('/')[3] + '/ws/rt');
  ws.onMessage(function (event) {
     // code that updates the page
  }):
```

In the server, I call the method sendText to send the data to the client.

```
  Ws.ACTIVE_SESSIONS.entrySet().stream().forEach((session) -> {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                session.getKey().getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
            }
        }
    });
```

The data that I am sending is composed by data and images, so it is a good amount of data.

My problem is that the server is sending this exception sometimes and the client doesn't get updated:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The remote endpoint
was in state [TEXT_FULL_WRITING] which is an invalid state for called 
method
```

I have already changed my OnMessage method to this, but it didn't solve the problem.

```
   @OnMessage
   public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
      ...
   }
```

What is the best way to do that and avoid this exception?